# JavaScript Collections API?

Tags: javascript, list, collections

I've searched quite a while for a Collections API (list, set) for JS and surprisingly I could only this: http://www.coffeeblack.org/work/jscollections/

This is exactly what I was looking for, but I'm wondering why doesn't jQuery provide that? What am I missing on? Or, perhaps, how ineffective are my searching techniques?

I know that arrays support pop() and push(), but I need contains() for example.

Comment: FYI - The coffeeblack collections library was a no-go for me because it adds properties to the javascript Object type's prototype.  This breaks some basic jquery functionality like $.css(map)

Comment: There's also https://github.com/kriskowal/collections

Answer (score 6):

You can try [js_cols](http://code.google.com/p/jscols/), a collections library for JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

Can't you use the jquery collection plugin.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Collection

Answer (score 5):

jQuery's primary focus is the DOM. It doesn't and shouldn't try and be all things to all people, so it doesn't have much in the way of collections support.

For maps and sets, I'd like to shamelessly point you in the direction of my own implementations of these: http://code.google.com/p/jshashtable/

Regarding lists, `Array` provides much of what you need. Like most methods you might want for arrays, you can knock together a `contains()` method in a few lines (most of which are to deal with IE <= 8's lack of support for the `indexOf()` method):

```
Array.prototype.contains = Array.prototype.indexOf ?
    function(val) {
        return this.indexOf(val) > -1;
    } :
    function(val) {
        var i = this.length;
        while (i--) {
            if (this[i] === val) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };

["a", "b", "c"].contains("a"); // true
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also try [buckets](https://github.com/mauriciosantos/buckets), it has the most used collections.

Answer (score 1):

Since javascript have both arrays `[]` and associative arrays `{}`, most needs for datstructures are already solved. The array solves the ordered list, fast access by numeric index whilst the associative array can be considered a unordered hashmap and solves the fast access by string keys.

For me that covers 95% of my data structure needs.

Comment: and what about contains(x)? Other than a loop what do you do?

Comment: If contains is the primary access way, I'd use an associative array. If I need ordered list *and* contains for very large data sets, I'd use both an array and associative array with the same data.

Comment: For small datasets I'd loop over the array.

Comment: trying to factor out loop code. Associative arrays are not enough, and how do I iterate over the elements once I don't know the values?

Answer (score 0):

If you get some free time you can checkout.
https://github.com/somnathpanja/jscollection