# Create List in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I used to create List in APS.net :

```
<% List<Item> list = new List<Item>(); %>
```

I want to create in jquery like this. How can I do that?
Anyone have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Why jQuery? I would think a plain [JavaScript array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) would do the same job as a list in other languages, given that JavaScript arrays don't have a fixed length.

Comment: Thanks nnnnnn for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some of possible solutions for you:
http://www.coffeeblack.org/work/jscollections/
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Collection

similar discussion:
[JavaScript Collections API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295937/javascript-collections-api)

Answer (score 2):

This is how you create a basic unordered list.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    list = jQuery('<ul>');
    listItem = jQuery('<li>new item</li>');
    list.append(listItem);
});
```